# How does Setting Up Notification when user leaves the app work?

Tags: android, android-notifications

I am new to coding.  I am using Android Studio with Java.  I spent the last 3 hours looking for how to set up a notification display at the top when the user leaves the app so they can always click on the notification when they want to return to the app but I couldn't find anything with that action I need.

The app tracks the users GPS and I want them to be able to always be aware that when the app is running it will continue to track their GPS.  So my idea is to have a notification window pop up whenever they leave the app so they can be aware the app is running in the background.

Any help will be much appreciated!  I am building this app on my own as a passion project and I am taking the Udacity Google Android course.  I finished the course early and working on this app for fun.  We didn't learn about Notifications or GPS tracking but I am doing my best to learn new things.  Thank you for your patience and help!

My app code is here for easy viewing:
https://github.com/PoetryHorizon/eloteroMan2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [foreground Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services). For any background logic, you should be using a Service anyway, and in Android Oreo and above, you're required to have it be a foreground Service, meaning it posts a Notification.

You can then add a PendingIntent to that notification set to reopen your app. See Android's [Notification documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification) on how to set a PendingIntent. You'll want to use `PendingIntent.getActivity()`, where the Intent you pass is `new Intent(someContext, YourActivity.class)`.